# Tests : Upgrade to Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rake, upgrade

I'm currently upgrading a huge application from rails 2.3 to rails 3.0. Everything worked well except for the tests, I'm experiencing a really strange bug.
Indeed, if I try to run **'rake test'**, all tests are returning an error ***'no route matches'***... But if I'm running them one by one with **'rake test:functionals TEST=/test/functional/my_test.rb'** it works like a charm...
I'm stuck on this since 2 days and I really don't understand what's happening... :(

If someone have any idea or suggestions to solve that bug... I would be happy to test it because I can't figure out where this problem come from ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but check out these threads:

[Rails 3 - no route matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203916/rails-3-routes-named-routes-no-route-matches)

[Rails 3 - route is failing, no route matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507187/simple-rails-3-route-is-failing-no-route-matches)

It seems they both have to do with an error in :method between :put and :post